# vector of objects actual process?

Tags: c++

This might be a very trivial question to ask but what does a vector of objects look like inside the memory in c++.

For example, consider the following class `edge`

```
class edge{
public:
    int sr{0};
    int ds{0};
    int wt{0};
    edge(){
    }
    edge(int sr,int ds,int wt){
        this->sr = sr;
        this->ds = ds;
        this->wt = wt;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,const edge& e)
    {
        return os << "< sr : " << e.sr << ", ds : " << e.ds << ", wt : " << e.wt << ">";
    }
};
```

Think of it as the edge of an directed graph where each edge has a source and a destination with a specified weight.

The `sr` here would mean `source` and `ds` is `destination` and `wt` is weight.

Now i want to create a `vector` of `edges`

What does the line `vector<edge> v(5)` do??

The way I think of it is that it would create a vector with 5 elements and then would make `edge` object at each `v[idx]` where `0 <= idx < v.size()`.

The second confusion that I have is let us say we have a class `p` defined as follows:

```
class p{
   public:
      edge first;
      edge second;
};
```

and let us suppose I created a `vector<p> v(5)` then what would happen ??

(My thought : The above statement would create a vector and then at each individual location it would make an object of class `p` and then would construct two edges inside each such object `p`.
This whole process would be repeated till `0 <= idx < v.size()(==5)`).

Is the way I am thinking correct or is there a flaw in my argument.

Any help would be appreciated?

**THOUGHT**

if the above process is true, isn't it too expensive??

Comment: Unrelated to your problem and question, but please don't abbreviate simple names for your variables. Why not name your variables `source`, `destination` and `weight`? Would make the code much easier to read and understand.

Comment: too expensive? If you ask for a vector with 5 elements of type `p` then thats what you get, why do you think this would be too expensive?

Comment: "What does the line vector<edge> v(5) do??" It fails to compile, `edge` doesn't have a default constructor. https://godbolt.org/z/eTqhxs98T

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number yeah but is my thought process correct.

Comment: As for your problem about things being "too expensive", my recommendation is to not worry about it until it's proven (by measuring, benchmarking and profiling). Concentrate on writing good, maintainable and *working* code, with plenty of unit-tests and that build cleanly with extra warnings enabled.

Comment: @RetiredNinja I have included the default constructor. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: [Continued] Then if there are requirements about performance, and the program doesn't fulfill those requirements, you take an optimized build and measure, benchmark and profile to find the top *one* bottleneck, and optimize that single bottleneck only, with plenty of documentation. Repeat until performance matches requirements and stop there. And most likely, the parts you seem to worry about in this question will probably not even be among the top ten bottlenecks of your program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude But is the process that I have mentioned correct??. Though, I am getting what you are saying.

Comment: @Abhishekjha Your thought process sounds right to me. C++ guarantees that in a vector the elements are laid out contiguously in memory.

Comment: This sounds like you have met some C gurus. They often tell us that C++ is bad, because it does things not directly visible in the code. Like in `vector<p> v(5)` they somehow cannot imagine that some constructors are run. We know that the constructors do *exactly* what is needed to initialize the objects. How can "exactly what is needed" be "too expensive"? So, don't listen to the false prophets!  :-)

Comment: Things are only too expensive after you have measured !!! that they are (with respect to your memory and or speed requirements), readability of code can also be very valuable (even be worth a bit of performance). Side note : Also do not underestimate the power of your compiler when it comes to (speed) optimizations [what has my compiler done for me lately](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bSkpMdDe4g4)

Comment: @BoP Actually that is very true. Most of the people around me are not genuinely interested in learning C++(They are just interested in doing X number of questions of DSA to get into a PBC). Initially, I also learned from them, due to which after a certain point of time I started hating C++ but deep down I always wanted to learn this language (simply because it is just awesome). But at times I do get frustrated because I am learning all this by myself. That is one of the reason I always directly ask (even the trivial questions) on stack overflow so that people who actually know C++ help me.

Comment: I can feel with you. I grew up in an environment where `std::vector` was considered "obscure". When I started to learn C++ (rather than C with classes) I was on my own because co-students claimed they already know it (they knew how to manually allocate arrays and deal with segfaults). Though, I wouldnt know how to write a good answer for this question. I suggest you to study some reference (i strongly recommend this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and try to be more specific (what exactly do you not understand after reading? Why do you think it would be "too expensive"?)

Comment: C programmers rarely quibble about performance or function of C code that allocates `some_struct *arr = malloc(3*sizeof(*arr))` and then separately initialises all elements of that dynamically allocated array (e.g. using a loop). But they moan loudly about arcane performance or other implications of `std::vector<some_struct> vec(3)` in C++. Yes, the C and C++ approaches differ in some nitty-gritties (the C++ standard specifies some aspects that the C standard doesn't, so C programmers must write more code) and the syntax obviously differs, but the two approaches achieve EXACTLY the same thing.

Comment: *if the above process is true, isn't it too expensive??*  Maybe it is too expensive.  Maybe not.  You have to **measure** the performance of your optimized code.  And then ascertain of the performance is within your requirements.  For the example given, you won't find any other programming language that will be more performant, so if it is too expensive you may need to consider some alternative approach that will meet the performance requirements.